# How do I assert within the first element of many in Capybara?

Tags: capybara, minitest

I want to do something like this:

```
within '.Collection .Thing:first-child' do
  page.must_have_content 'lorem ipsum'
end
```

Where `.Thing` is just one of many other Things inside Collection. I tried the code above but it says it's ambiguous. Is there a way to resolve the ambiguity?

Comment: Oculd you paste page source for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really just want the first matching element on the page you can do

```
within first('.Collection .Thing:first-child', minimum: 1) do
  page.must_have_content 'lorem ipsum'
end
```

the minimum: 1 option isn't necessarily needed if the page is already fully loaded, however it will make Capybara wait for at least one matching element to show on the page if the page isn't yet fully loaded (or the list is filled via ajax, etc).  Without it #first would normally return immediately with nil if no matching elements were on the page

Comment: Didn't know I could `first` with `within`. Very useful, thanks!

Comment: @Granada yep, from the docs http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#within-instance_method. It can accept a node to be used as the scope which is what the finders return